# How can a question have more votes than views?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, up-votes

I'm sorry if this question seems silly, but I really find the situation suprising.

When I looked at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658562/prove-that-1-kappax-y-is-a-symmetric-bilinear-form-2-kappax-y-z-k) earlier, it had 9 views and 10 upvotes. Since people can only vote once, this should clearly be impossible, especially if the question asker counts as one view (I'm not sure if that's the case or not). Note that I am probably counted as one view but I did not vote on the question. Besides, these votes arrived very fast : I find unusual to get 10 upvotes in only 5 minutes, especially for a question that is essentially a PSQ (a higher level than your average PSQ, but still not giving much more than the statement of a problem).

Is this normal? Could it be a simple bug?

Comment: Consider the likelihood of such an event, though, if possible. In my honest opinion, nonetheless, I think it might be a bug, or the post was deleted and then reopened or something like that.

Comment: It's the holy ghost, of course.

Comment: Maybe the view count is not updated as fast as the vote count.

Comment: @GEdgar It's possible, of course, but at some point I refreshed the page (which would have updated both counts, I think) and it had 10 votes and 10 views. Since I have not voted, that is still (at least) one more vote than views.

Comment: There's an explanation of how the caching works on view counts here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80857/203972